# 4-way handshake failed with freeradius on openWrt?

Tags: openwrt, freeradius

I used `freeradius-server` on `openWrt` to get sim IMSI. Because I did have some sim value(rand, sres, kc),I changed the source code use fake value. It can be authenticated successfully. But in the process of 4-way handshake, it failed! It just have one handshake.

I captured some package with wireshark, anyone can help me analysis the reason or have a better way to get imsi on `openWrt`?

**eap-sim authenticate process**

[image: eap-sim authenticate process]

**handshake 1 of 4**

[image: handshake 1 of 4]

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason!
At the begining, I do not have the sim value(RAND, sres, kc), so I create some fake value. The code need the correct **msk** value to build up PMK package, like these:

```
static int eap_sim_sendsuccess(EAP_HANDLER *handler)
{
    unsigned char *p;
    struct eap_sim_server_state *ess;
    VALUE_PAIR **outvps;
    VALUE_PAIR *newvp;

    /* outvps is the data to the client. */
    outvps= &handler->request->reply->vps;
    ess = (struct eap_sim_server_state *)handler->opaque;

    /* set the EAP_ID - new value */
    newvp = paircreate(ATTRIBUTE_EAP_ID, PW_TYPE_INTEGER);
    newvp->vp_integer = ess->sim_id++;
    pairreplace(outvps, newvp);

    p = ess->keys.msk;   //**look here**!
    add_reply(outvps, "MS-MPPE-Recv-Key", p, EAPTLS_MPPE_KEY_LEN);
    p += EAPTLS_MPPE_KEY_LEN;
    add_reply(outvps, "MS-MPPE-Send-Key", p, EAPTLS_MPPE_KEY_LEN);
    return 1;
}
```

So, It built a wrong PMK package. The mobile phone recieved the 1/4 handshake and droped it.